# How to solve application-defined or object-defined error in VBA?

Tags: microsoft-excel, vba

I got `application-defined or object-defined error` every time I press "run"

```
Sub Test1()
    Dim Bank As Range
    Dim lRow As Long

    lRow = Cells(Rows.Count, 3).End(xlUp).Row
    Bank = Worksheets("Deposits Calculator").Range(Cells(3, 9), Cells(lRow, 9))

    Do While Bank <> 0
        If (lRow = 9) Then
            Cells(9, 3).Select
            ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "='Deposit Calculator' !R[5]C[9]"
        End If
    Loop
End Sub
```

Comment: If you step through the Subroutine (Debug menu, or CTRL-Shift I), which line gives you the error?

Comment: Bank = Worksheets("Deposits Calculator").Range(Cells(3, 9), Cells(lRow, 9)) this line

Answer (score 1):

You need to use the `Set` keyword when assigning an object:

```
Set Bank = Worksheets("Deposits Calculator").Range(Cells(3, 9), Cells(lRow, 9))
```

Comment: I tried but it still show the same error

Comment: Are you certain that a worksheet named "Deposits Calculator" exists in the ActiveWorkbook?